# Notification for Android MediaPlayer

Tags: android, notifications, android-mediaplayer

I'm new to Android and at the moment I'm developing a MediaPlayer for online streaming. The mediaplayer runs fine and everything, but I'm having a problem with the Notification. When I press "play" the Notification appears in the notification bar and when I click on the notification in the notification bar it start a new activity instead of displaying the current one.
I don't know if I'm using the wrong FLAG for the PendingIntent for this Application.

My Code Looks like This:

```
public void Notification_Inicialization()
{
Intent intent = new Intent(this,radio_app_3.class);


PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
res = getApplicationContext().getResources();

app_notification = new Notification.Builder(this).setTicker(tickerTitle).setContentTitle(title)
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.android_icon).setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.ic_launcher))
.setContentIntent(pendingIntent).addAction(R.drawable.android_icon,"Play",pendingIntent)
.getNotification();

notification_layout = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),R.layout.activity_radio_app_3);

notification_layout.setTextViewText(R.id.button_play,getString(R.string.app_name));

notification_layout.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button_play,pendingIntent);

app_notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(uniqueID,app_notification);

}
```

Hope someone can give me a help with this problem
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please paste the fragment of the manifest that have that activity declaration?

Comment: Thanks for your respond. I solve it by declaring the mediaplayer activity as "SingleTask".